# EVR: transparent textout on video window

Tags: delphi, directshow

On the form the button, trackbar, the panel (panel1 - the successor from tpanel + is added canvas, align=client),
I start video through EVR on the panel (tpanel)

```
...
FGraph: IGraphBuilder;
FEVR: IBaseFilter;
FDisplayControl: IMFVideoDisplayControl;
...

OnBtnclik>>

if not Succeeded (CoCreateInstance (CLSID_FilterGraph, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, FGraph)) then Exit;
if not Succeeded (CoCreateInstance (CLSID_EnhancedVideoRenderer, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IBaseFilter, FEVR)) then Exit;
FGraph. AddFilter (FEVR, 'EVR');
(FEVR as IMFGetService).GetService (MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE, IID_IMFVideoDisplayControl, FDisplayControl);
FDisplayControl. SetVideoWindow (Panel1.Handle); 
UpdateEvr; // resize
FGraph. RenderFile (PWideChar ('c:\video\myvideo.avi'), nil);
FDisplayControl. SetAspectRatioMode (0);
...

OntrackbarChange>>
...
    with panel1.Canvas do
      begin
        Font. Color: = cllime;
        Brush. Style: = bsclear;
        Font. Size: = 20;
        TextOut (10, 10, ' TRANSPARENT TEXT ');
      end;
```

The text is displayed, but flickers. How to deduce the normal transparent text on panel1 during video playing?

CG.E.Rad 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.delphibbs.com/keylife/iblog_show.asp?xid=33152

in procedure TEVR9Demo.VideoPlay;

first step - add:

```
image1.canvas.Brush.Color:=clblack;
image1.Canvas.FloodFill(10,10,clblack,fsborder);
image1.Canvas.FloodFill(10,10,clblack,fsSurface);
image1.Canvas.Font.Color:=cllime;
image1.Canvas.Font.Size:=24;
image1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsclear;
image1.Canvas.TextOut(10,10,'TRANSPARENT TEXT EXAMPLE');
```

e!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd to me that you are painting during the track bar change event. Why don't you paint in an overridden `Paint` method? That would allow you to do double-buffering if all other attempts at flicker reduction failed.

That said, I'd probably avoid custom painting if possible. I'd use a `TLabel` to display the text and it will paint as part of the paint cycle. If you still had flicker problems then you might find `TStaticText` flickers less that `TLabel`.

Comment: If on the panel to put tlabel (caption: ='Example ') and to make its property trasparent=true at video playing - it disappears, "is rubbed clean" video ( Even if tlabel to update on the timer ).
Can there is other method? If it is simple, write a code example.

Comment: I guess the issue is the control that's drawing the video. It's hard to advise you without know how that is done. Does it have its own window handle? Can you paint in `Paint`? Does using a transparent TStaticText help?

Comment: Has now tried through TjvPanel (Jedi components):

procedure TForm1.Panel3Paint (Sender: TObject);
begin
//label1.Refresh;
with panel3.Canvas do
  begin
    Font. Color: = cllime;
    Brush. Style: = bsclear;
    Font. Size: = 20;
    TextOut (10, 10, ' HELLO ');
  end;
end;
All the same flickers :(

Comment: try setting the font and brush properties on form construction and just leaving the TextOut call. Also, why do you paint in a trackbar change event? Why don't you paint in a Paint method? And how does this video control paint? Do you have any knowledge of how it works?

Comment: ... Has read, that in VMR it is used certain "VMR9AlphaBitmap". Can for EVR something similar is? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/957625e5-8160-49b2-8b1f-b6a0e6e8cd4a/

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by the DirectShow engine drawing the video on top of your label. You are "re-freshing" your label when you paint it on the track bar event, but the refresh rate of the video playpack will never be the same as your track bar events, so the flickering occurs. I think there is no way of getting this approach to work.
I recommend to take a look in the sample code "Text" and "Text9" on Summer 2004 DirectX DSK Update as stated in the following post: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32121970/placing-text-overlay-on-direct-show-video.aspx
Those sample codes are written in C++, but it should not be too difficult to translate them to Delphi.

Comment: In the bottom answer I wrote to comments, that for EVR it does not work. Examples of work of the normal transparent text I saw, they are in DsPack, but there all work is made for VMR-7 and 9, for EVR at me it has not turned out to make it.

Comment: I see, I did not notice you were using EVR rendering. I think in this case your only choice is to implement a transform filter and add it to your graph (see a similar post here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/8F972B65-FA33-452A-B7C1-06D45F41080F). There are samples on transform filters in Windows Platform SDK and in DSPack. If you can afford a commercial solution, you could take a look at this product: http://www.medialooks.com/products/directshow_filters/chargen.html